# Angular2 do not listen to events on a Component

Tags: angular

Can I make a component which will not listen to click / mousemove / ... events?

Is there a way to say to angular2 not to track changes on specific component?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking about. Please improve your question, if possible add some code that demonstrates what you actually try to accomplish. If you don't register event handlers than Angular ignores these events.

Comment: Try the detach() method of ChangeDetectorRef: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.htm

Comment: @MarkRajcok make it an answer :D

Comment: But @EricMartinez, I'm trying to be like you :) and only add one-line succinct comments sometimes, lol.

Comment: Hahaha, I lol'd. Well it's up to you :P

Answer (score 1):

To turn off change detection for a component, call the `detatch()` method of [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.htm):

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
     _cdr.detach();  // detaches the change detector from the change detector tree
  }
```